# Insert blog post with tags in a PostgreSQL database using node-postgres (pg)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to create an API with node and express for my blog app.
The API is talking to a PostgreSQL database using node-postgres (pg).

A user tries to create a blog post and submits a POST request to the server containing the following data:

```
{
   "title": "This is the title",
   "content": "This is the content",
   "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}
```

I don't know if this is a good idea but I was thinking of inserting the data like this:

**posts table:**

| post_id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is the title | This is the content |

**tags table:**

| tag_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 |
| 2 | tag2 |
| 3 | tag3 |

**posts_tags table:**

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

The problem is that I have no clue how to insert the data in this manner with node-postgres (pg).

How would you go about doing this?

Is there a better way of doing this?

### UPDATE:

I managed to do it.

This is the function i created.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addPost(
    title_input VARCHAR(255),
    content_input TEXT,
    tags_input VARCHAR(25)[],
    user_id_input INT
) RETURNS SETOF posts as $$
    DECLARE
        p_id INT;
        t_id INT;
        _tag VARCHAR(25);
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO posts (title, content, user_id) 
                VALUES (title_input, content_input, user_id_input) RETURNING post_id INTO p_id;
       
        FOREACH _tag IN ARRAY tags_input LOOP 
                SELECT tag_id INTO t_id FROM tags WHERE name = _tag;
                
                IF t_id IS NULL THEN
                    INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES (_tag) RETURNING tag_id INTO t_id;
                    INSERT INTO posts_tags (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (p_id, t_id);
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO posts_tags (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (p_id, t_id);
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
            
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = p_id;
    END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

... and this is how i call it

```sql
SELECT * FROM addPost(
    'This is the title',
    'This is the content',
    '{tag1, tag2, tag3}'::VARCHAR(25)[],
    1
);
```

I am a beginner with SQL.
I am not sure if this is the optimal way of doing it.
I would love to hear some thoughts on the code above and how I could improve it.

Comment: The database design looks alright. Insertion involves several tables and even a loop (look up `tag_id` for each tag, inserting new tags if necessary), and you must first decide whether to implement these steps in Node.js, or rather in a PostgreSQL database procedure. In the Node.js case, you must use SQL statements `begin` and `commit` to encapsulate your database transactions.

Comment: Hi @Heiko Theißen. Thanks for your suggestions. I managed to come up with a solution. I decided that it's best to implement the steps in PostgreSQL. Could you please review the function I created and tell me if you'd change anything?

Comment: LGTM, but I am no real PostgreSQL expert.